# Error installing Windows 8.1 to a previously formatted HDD

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, installation

I have used Partition Magic to format my 500 GB hard drive.

I have created 3 partitions as follows.

- C:\  80 GB NTFS, I will install windows in it
- D:\ 70 GB EXT4 , I want to install Ubuntu on it later
- E:\ The rest about 315 GB is partition for data storage

I am trying to install windows 8.1 from a USB drive, into the C partition, but when I select C I get the following error:

```
"Cannot create new partition or locate existed one"
```

When I delete the partition C and create a new partition, then I can continue the installation. But it is creating extra 3 small partitions, about 100MB each, name like "System Reverse".

Is there any way I can install Windows without creating any extra partitions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't create partition or locate existing one when installing windows 8.1](http://superuser.com/questions/772457/cant-create-partition-or-locate-existing-one-when-installing-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just walk through without creating those extra partitions it will be created automatically for system reserve. but it will only create one why it is creating more than one I thing your doing something wrong.

See this question for your error
[Can't create partition or locate existing one when installing windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/772457/cant-create-partition-or-locate-existing-one-when-installing-windows-8-1?rq=1)

Comment: Two partition, exactly, one name "Recovery Partition" and one "EFI System partition"

Comment: well windows 8.1 will create this partitions there is nothing wrong in that

Comment: Yes, thankyou. I just converted my disk from MBR to UEFI, in MBR I don't meet these little partition, so I think may be I do something wrong cause the disk fragmented